# Which is the Best method to add authentication WPF / Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, aspnetdb

I have two different applications **using the same aspnetdb database** - a WPF application which is in premises and an online silverlight application. I need to manage users in the aspnetdb database(create/edit/assign roles etc).

Whether I should create a datamodel for aspnetdb and use the linq query or whether I should use the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider for managing the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a WCF service that exposes Login methods. You'll need one anyway for your Silverlight app I presume.
Then you can "add service reference" to your new WCF service in both projects and login through it.

Comment: Hi Baboon, thanks for your answer. The two applications are in two different premises. Can we still add the service reference to the WPF application. Also, can we use the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in the WPF application as I have currently done a sample using that.

Comment: You can absolutely add the service reference to the WPF app, same way as for the Silverlight app. I personally do a Logon splashscreen usually. As for the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, only the WCf service needs to know about it. Your clients (WPF & Silverlight apps) just send the credentials, they're not supposed to know what they really log on to.

Comment: Hi Baboon, I am new to the WCF concept. Is this WCF service created seaprately (in WPF or Silverlight). Is the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider necessary for creating the service?

Comment: You need to make a new WCF project, that will be hosted separately from your apps. A common good practice is to access the WCF service through a DAL (one per project), and the DAL should have the service reference. There a tutorials all over the web for WCF =)